# Вывод выпадающего списка на сайте используя tv

Tags: cms, modx, revo

Дорого времени суток!

Задача в следующем: нужно вывести допустимые значение дополнительного поля.

```
Тип ввода: Список (множественный выбор)
Возможные значения: @SELECT fullname FROM  modx_user_attributes
```

Если добавлять через админку то все как надо. Но нужно это дело и на сайте вывести.

Не подскажете способ или может кто делал подобное?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если требуется выводить элементы, которые были выбраны в созданном Вами дополнительном поле (*с типом - множественный выбор*), то можно "разбирать" результат сниппетом. Предварительно поставив в **Параметрах вывода - разделитель**. (запятую, к примеру). 
`[[!Dropdown? &listItem='[[*myTv]]']]`

**Код спиппета:**

```
$listItems = explode(',', $listItem);

$tpl = '<option value="[[+listItem]]">[[+listItem]]</option>';
$output = '<select multiple="multiple">';

foreach ($listItems as $item) {
    $output .= "\n" . str_replace('[[+listItem]]', $item, $tpl);
}

$output .= "\n</select>";
return $output;
```

На выходе получим список множественного выбора с элементами, которые были отмечены при редактировании/создании ресурса.

---

Если же, Вам просто требуется вывести на сайте необходимые значения из таблицы `modx_user_attributes`, то можно воспользоваться методом `getCollection`

```
$output = '<select multiple="multiple">';

$tpl = '<option value="[[+listItem]]">[[+listItem]]</option>';

$where = array();
$userProps = $modx->getCollection('modUserProfile', $where);
foreach ($userProps as $userProp) {
    $output .= "\n" . str_replace('[[+listItem]]', $userProp->get('fullname'), $tpl);
}
$output .= "\n</select>"; 

return $output;
```